# Meteor.js and MongoDB, I have problems manipulating my Databases

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am absolutely new to both MongoDB and Meteor.js. I am trying to follow a tutorial, and despite the fact that I am reproducing exactly what the teacher does, I am stuck. I am trying to display the list of items from the database `entries` but nothing shows up. I tried many ways, and console.logged quite a lot but I never managed to get it working.

Here are my files:

1/ main.html

```
<body>
  <h3 class="title">Welcome!</h3>

  <div class="container list">
    <ul class="collection">
      {{#each entries}}
        {{> list}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

<template name="list">
  <li class="collection-item"> {{title}}
  </li>
</template>
```

2/ main.js

```
import { event } from 'jquery';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Entries } from '../lib/collection.js';

import './main.html';

Template.body.helpers({
  entries(){
    return [Entries.find({})];
  },
});
```

3/ collection.js

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Entries = new Mongo.Collection('entries');
```

And here is the database that I have created in the command line after running `meteor mongo`, and when I type in the command: `db.entries.find().pretty()`

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f69ef84eda325daca4b0d51"),
        "title" : "Hello",
        "content" : "try hard"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f69f0db434cda7b7f21d193"),
        "title" : "Hello",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-22T12:40:59.924Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f69f1c8434cda7b7f21d194"),
        "title" : "Hello",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-22T12:44:56.230Z")
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f69f2c3434cda7b7f21d195"), "name" : "Watercress" }
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f69f6012a6382ef314d84cb"),
        "title" : "goodbye",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-22T13:02:57.511Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f69f6bf2a6382ef314d84cd"),
        "title" : "fresh",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-22T13:06:07.561Z")
}
```

If you could help, that would be great!

Comment: did you tried to log the db, does it contains the data?

Comment: return Entries.find({});

Comment: Yes sorry it used to be ```return Entries.find({}); ``` I don't know why I changed it. Unfortunately it is still not working.
I tried to console.log the db without much success. When I console.log(Entries.find());
I get something like this:

Cursor
collection: LocalCollection {name: "entries", _docs: _IdMap, _observeQueue: M…r._SynchronousQueue, next_qid: 2, queries: {…}, …}
fields: undefined
limit: undefined
matcher: Matcher {_paths: {…}, _hasGeoQuery: false, _hasWhere: false, _isSimple: true, _matchingDocument: undefined, …}
reactive: true

etc.

Comment: Yes that's a cursor. If you want to see the documents you need to `console.log(Entries.find().fetch())`. In order to get the documents to the client you need to [publish them on the server and subscribe on the client](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html), did you do that? If so, please add their code to the question.

Comment: No I don't think I did any of that. I just followed this tutorial, and I don't se anything about publishing to a server at this point: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app
Sorry, it's all very new to me.

Comment: If you have auto publish disabled then you won't be able to access the data unless you publish and subscribe to it. can you kindly check that. I think it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, it's quite frustrating to start off on a tutorial, facing that it's not working as expected, and I hope the following tips help you diving into how Meteor and its magic work.

1. Ensure the collection is registered both on the server and the client. For you this means, ensure the file `collection.js` runs on both environments. You can confirm this by putting a `console.log()` into the file. If you see the output on both the terminal and in the console of the browser, continue. This is specially important when using `autopublish` package.
2. Ensure the data is published to the client. This happens by either

   2.1 installing the package `autopublish` (have a look at the file `.meteor/packages`. In case you don't have it, you can install it using `meteor add autopublish`) or

   2.2 jump right away to manually publishing the data (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe).


   Install the extension [Meteor DevTools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meteor-devtools/ippapidnnboiophakmmhkdlchoccbgje), open the developer toolbar, switch to the tab `Meteor` and there to the inner tab `Minimongo` to confirm the data has arrived at the browser.
3. Now it's the job of Blaze to get informed about the changes (that data is coming into the collection on the browser) and updating it.

Here's a very good article about [Meteors publications & subscriptions](http://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/). It's old but gold for understanding the concept.

If you have questions where you have the impression it needs a back-and-forth communication, please join the [the Meteor community on Slack](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/organization#slack).

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for this very encouraging comment and for your amazing help. And sorry for the delay, I got caught up on something else lately, but I will definitely look this up and accept this answer as soon as I do. Thank you!!!